# Javascript sliding image gallery, ... how?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering of any of you could push me in the right direction :).
I'm trying 2 make an image "sliding" gallery, but it is a little complicated.
it has 2 have 3 or 5 "views" the mainview ( the one you are currently watching) a previous and a next.
The previous and the next must dynamically load images and unload them when they are 2 positions out of view.

So what it comes down to, i have 150 images i want to display in a sliding gallery and i only want to load 5 at a time if i scroll 2 the right image one should be unloaded and image 3,4,5 and 6 should be loaded and image 2 should be displayed.
I have no real experience with Javascript.

(It should look alot like iphone Photo App :))

Kind Regards,
Bart

Comment: "it has 2 have 3 or 5" made me try to laugh and cry at the same time

Comment: Yeah i know :D srry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to take a look at jQuery javascript library, because it'll help you in document manipulation.

Having this, you can use AJAX.

I'd suggest you to do that:

1) The images are dinamically loaded, meaning that when an user ask for the next N pics (let's say, 5), some AJAX script will request for the next N pics, preloading them with the Javascript's Image object.

2) Using jQuery, you can create slideshow-style transition animations.

3) Finally, depending on your target users, you can take advantage of HTML5, but you know that its support is limited to a very small percentage of global internet audience.